# Vert.x log statement parameterized with a Lambda Expression

Tags: java, logging, lambda, vert.x

I want to add some extra debug information in a project based on Vert.x that happens to use `io.vertx.core.logging.Logger` for logging.

As far as I can see by looking at [the Javadoc](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/logging/Logger.html), the class doesn't provide a method with a signature matching a functional interface.

The log message I want to output can be based on a sizeable collection of values. I'd like to avoid transforming it unnecessarily.

That seems to leave me with the following pattern:

```
if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOGGER.debug(buildMyLargeCollectionsStringRepresentation());
}
```

This, on the other hand, makes my code check for `isDebugEnabled()` time and time again.

I'd rather leave it up to the framework for both brevity and potential optimization.

Is there a way to use a supplier in a way similar to the [`java.util.Logger class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. But with a little care, you can probably do without the guard functions like `isDebugEnabled()`. Loggers typically check the log level inside of logging functions before formatting the string. If it does decide that the logging level matches, it will do the string formatting, which includes calling `toString()` on any parameters that are passed in to be included in the formatted string. If you avoid complex expressions passed directly into logger methods and instead encapsulate your expressions in an object whose `toString()` function evaluates the expression you wish to log, then you might achieve the benefit of the guard expressions without having to use them.

I'm not sure how vertx binds its apis to JUL logging.  It may be that the first Object parameter will be passed as the Supplier parameter in JUL.  If not, you might try the technique below which can be adapted for any general string logging mechanism that calls toString() on its parameters.

Consider the following, which uses slf4j's parameter notation:

```
debug("Doing something with {}", some_expression_that_is_expensive);
```

In this example, `some_expression_that_is_expensive` would be called every time the `debug` function is called, whether or not debug logging is enabled. If you instead had a class such as

```
class EncapsulatedExpression {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return some_expression_that_is_expensive;
    }
}
```

Then you could call

```
debug("Doing something with {}", new EncapsulatedExpression());
```

And then `some_expression_that_is_expensive` would only be called if the log level were debug.

You are on the right track by saying that a `Supplier` would offer similar lazy evaluation in a more general way, so to get what you want you will need a tool to create something that can encapsulate a `Supplier`, whose `toString()` will cause the supplier to be evaluated.  Perhaps something like this would work:

```
class ToStringSupplier<T> {
    private Supplier<T> supplier;

    public ToStringSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier){
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public static <T> ToStringSupplier<T> lazily(Supplier<T> supplier){
        return new ToStringSupplier<>(supplier);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return Objects.toString(supplier.get());  // supplier could safely return null
    }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
debug("Doing something with {}", lazily(() -> some_expression_that_is_expensive));
```